# Python thread not listening to flag

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm using a slightly edited example from [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks). The start button in the GUI starts a thread, the stop button stops it. I've added an x = x+1 and a print(x) to the loop, that works too. But if I try to bring x to the GUI, the stop button stops working. I don't understand why. Can you explain it to me?

The code is below. Running it like this will give you the result after stopping the thread. Uncommenting line 48 will give you the result every 1 second, but the stop button will stop working.

```
import time
from threading import *
import wx

# Button definitions
ID_START = wx.NewId()
ID_STOP = wx.NewId()

# Define notification event for thread completion
EVT_RESULT_ID = wx.NewId()

def EVT_RESULT(win, func):
    """Define Result Event."""
    win.Connect(-1, -1, EVT_RESULT_ID, func)

class ResultEvent(wx.PyEvent):
    """Simple event to carry arbitrary result data."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        """Init Result Event."""
        wx.PyEvent.__init__(self)
        self.SetEventType(EVT_RESULT_ID)
        self.data = data
        pass

# Thread class that executes processing
class WorkerThread(Thread):
    """Worker Thread Class."""
    def __init__(self, notify_window):
        """Init Worker Thread Class."""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._notify_window = notify_window
        self._want_abort = 0
        # This starts the thread running on creation, but you could
        # also make the GUI thread responsible for calling this
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        """Run Worker Thread."""
        # This is the code executing in the new thread. Simulation of
        # a long process (well, 10s here) as a simple loop - you will
        # need to structure your processing so that you periodically
        # peek at the abort variable
        x=0
        for i in range(10):
            x = x + 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print(x)
            #wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, ResultEvent(x))
            if self._want_abort:
                # Use a result of None to acknowledge the abort (of
                # course you can use whatever you'd like or even
                # a separate event type)
                wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, ResultEvent('ended with ' + str(x)))
                return
        # Here's where the result would be returned (this is an
        # example fixed result of the number 10, but it could be
        # any Python object)
        wx.PostEvent(self._notify_window, ResultEvent(10))

    def abort(self):
        """abort worker thread."""
        # Method for use by main thread to signal an abort
        self._want_abort = 1

# GUI Frame class that spins off the worker thread
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Class MainFrame."""
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        """Create the MainFrame."""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Thread Test')

        # Dumb sample frame with two buttons
        wx.Button(self, ID_START, 'Start', pos=(0,0))
        wx.Button(self, ID_STOP, 'Stop', pos=(0,50))
        self.status = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '', pos=(0,100))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, id=ID_START)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, id=ID_STOP)

        # Set up event handler for any worker thread results
        EVT_RESULT(self,self.OnResult)

        # And indicate we don't have a worker thread yet
        self.worker = None

    def OnStart(self, event):
        """Start Computation."""
        # Trigger the worker thread unless it's already busy
        if not self.worker:
            self.status.SetLabel('Starting computation')
            self.worker = WorkerThread(self)

    def OnStop(self, event):
        """Stop Computation."""
        # Flag the worker thread to stop if running
        if self.worker:
            self.status.SetLabel('Trying to abort computation')
            self.worker.abort()

    def OnResult(self, event):
        """Show Result status."""
        if event.data is None:
            # Thread aborted (using our convention of None return)
            self.status.SetLabel('Computation aborted')
        else:
            # Process results here
            self.status.SetLabel('Computation Result: %s' % event.data)
        # In either event, the worker is done
        self.worker = None

class MainApp(wx.App):
    """Class Main App."""
    def OnInit(self):
        """Init Main App."""
        self.frame = MainFrame(None, -1)
        self.frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found the classic example but it is now very dated. Either look for a modern example or pick the bones out of the following:

```
import time
import wx
from threading import Thread

import wx.lib.newevent
progress_event, EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class ThreadFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent, title=title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(panel,label='Stop Long running process', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)
        self.progress = wx.Gauge(panel,size=(240,10), pos=(10,50), range=240)

        #Bind to the progress event issued by the thread
        self.Bind(EVT_PROGRESS_EVENT, self.OnProgress)
        #Bind to Exit on frame close
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)
        self.Show()

        self.mythread = TestThread(self)
        #Enable the GUI to be responsive by briefly returning control to the main App
        while self.mythread.isAlive():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            wx.GetApp().Yield()
            continue

        try:
            self.OnExit(None)
        except:
            pass

    def OnProgress(self, event):
        self.progress.SetValue(event.count)
        #or for indeterminate progress
        #self.progress.Pulse()

    def OnExit(self, event):
        if self.mythread.isAlive():
            self.mythread.terminate() # Shutdown the thread
            self.mythread.join() # Wait for it to finish
        self.Destroy()

class TestThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,parent_target):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent_target
        self.stopthread = False
        self.time = time.time()
        self.start()    # start the thread

    def run(self):
        # A loop that will run for 2 minutes then terminate
        while self.stopthread == False:
            curr_loop = int(time.time() - self.time)
            if curr_loop < 240:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                evt = progress_event(count=curr_loop)
                #Send back current count for the progress bar
                try:
                    wx.PostEvent(self.parent, evt)
                except: # The parent frame has probably been destroyed
                    self.terminate()
            else:
                self.terminate()

    def terminate(self):
        self.stopthread = True

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text_count = 0
        self.thread_count = 0
        self.parent=parent
        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Start Long running process', size=(200,30), pos=(10,10))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Thread_Frame)
        btn2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label='Is the GUI still active?', size=(200,30), pos=(10,50))
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.AddText)
        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE, pos=(10,90),size=(400,100))

    def Thread_Frame(self, event):
        self.thread_count += 1
        frame = ThreadFrame(title='Threaded Task '+str(self.thread_count), parent=self.parent)

    def AddText(self,event):
        self.text_count += 1
        txt = "Gui is still active " + str(self.text_count)+"\n"
        self.txt.write(txt)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Main Frame', size=(600,400))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the yield approach a go. Is that the best way to do this? And: I copy pasted your code, but for me the program closes right away. I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Use python 3 and run from the command line to see errors and traceback. The `yield` is ensure that the main GUI remains responsive, rather than locking up, until such time that the thread completes.